# Javascript setDate() bug

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to make a function that changes a li element in such a way that it shows the date of the next week every time the Next week button is pressed but I don't know how to check if a new month has started using the ***setDate()*** method.

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
const elemen = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh"];
var weeknumber = 0;

function setweek() {
  let d = new Date();
  const start = d.getDate();
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    d.setDate(start + i)
    document.getElementById(elemen[i]).innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + '<br>' + d.getDate() + "." + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  }
}

function addweek() {
  weeknumber++;
  let d = new Date();
  const start = d.getDate();
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    d.setDate(start + i + (weeknumber * 7));
    // In this code I need a if function too check if a month has passed so it sets the weeknumber to 0.
    document.getElementById(elemen[i]).innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + '<br>' + d.getDate() + "." + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="setweek();">
  <label for="weekly_meal_plan">Weekly meal plan:</label><br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="weekly_meal_plan">
    <li id="first" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="second" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="third" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="fourth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="fifth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="sixth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="seventh" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <button id="nweek" onclick="addweek();">Next week</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry its not a bug, I just don't understand how to check if a month has passed in setDate().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: @Titulum unfortunately no, using the answer with the highest points will just get it stuck to 8.12 for every li element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function addweek() {
  weeknumber++;
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    let d = new Date();
    const start = d.getDate();
    d.setDate(start + i + (weeknumber * 7));
    // In this code I need a if function too check if a month has passed so it sets the weeknumber to 0.
    document.getElementById(elemen[i]).innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + '<br>' + d.getDate() + "." + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  }
}
```

Now, at every iteration of the loop, the starting date gets resetted to today.

The problem of your code was that once you use `setDate(32)`, the month would permanently change. In the next iteration, you would use `setDate(33)` on the NEW date, with the month already incremented.

Comment: Yes, this works. I thought to add a if function that would change the weeknumber to 0 but this is way better. Thank you.